# how to give permission to another user in sql

Tags: mysql

```
GRANT PRIVILEGE ON database.table TO 'username'@'host';
ERROR 1046 (3D000): No database selected

GRANT CREATE, ALTER, DROP, INSERT, UPDATE, INDEX, DELETE, SELECT, REFERENCES, RELOAD on *.* TO 'sammy'@'localhost' WITH GRANT OPTION;
```

Comment: That shouldn't happen. The default database is only used when you don't specify a database explicitly. But you explicitly used `database.table`

Comment: But you can just select the database: `USE database`